# Report Viewer and designer in javascript/angularjs Library

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, reportviewer, syncfusion

I am using Angularjs and I have WEB API (.NET) as a back end.
I have been looking for an open source and nice report-viewer and designer.

I have used Microsoft's RDLC Report Layouts in Visual Studio which I haven't found it very comprehensive & flexible and I stumble upon [syncfusion report viwer](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejreportviewer) which was nice.
 But still, it has documentation issue on angularJS.

Can anyone help me in getting me a nice tool (better be open-source) to have this kind of print-outs.
[image: print out sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncfusion JavaScript ReportViewer controls helps to view RDL/RDLC standard reports within web application. The shared link (https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejreportviewer) is the description about ReportViewer control and you can find the complete UG documentation to create a ReportViewer control in Angular platform from below location,
https://help.syncfusion.com/angular-1/reportviewer/getting-started

And I have prepared a sample using Syncfusion ReportViewer control which can be downloaded from below location,
Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ReportDemo977483098.zip